# configure mysql and apache2 module in webmin

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, webmin

This question might not be appropriate to ask in this forum but unfortunately the linux stack forum is not as active as here.

I installed mysql and apache2 successfully on my linux (kaliv2 x64 on vmware) and used it. I decided to use webmin as well but I have been facing some problems:

for mysql it says

1. The MySQL startup script (/usr/bin/safe_mysqld was not found on your system. Maybe MySQL is not installed, or your module configuration is incorrect

I can not find *safe_mysqld* in my directories. apparently *safe_mysqld* has been changed to *mysqld.sock* (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) however when I change */usr/bin/safe_mysqld* to *mysql.sock* I still facing the error.

[image]

for apache2

2. The Apache configuration file /etc/apache2 does not exist. If you have Apache installed, adjust the module configuration to use the correct path.

I should mention that Apache Webserver is located in unused modules

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all configuration for MySQL is correct except

"Command to start MySQL server" : /etc/init.d/mysql

And for Apache I did as below

1. "Apache server root directory" :/etc/apache2
2. "Path to httpd executable" :/etc/init.d/apache2
3. "Path to httpd.conf or apache2.conf" :/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
4. "Path to access.conf" : Automatic

Answer (score 0):

Use `locate` command to find `mysqld_safe`, `apache2` and maybe `apachectl`. In case you couldn't find `mysqld_safe`, look for `mysqld`. As for `apache2` look for BOTH file and directory with this name - the first one is a command to start and stop the service, the second one is the server root directory which contains `bin/httpd` and `bin/apachectl`.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply but it gives me lots of Path list that is too difficult to find which one is correct. I check some of them but nothing happened